Using pgloader to migrate SQL to Postgres. Can't figure out how to write to a different scema than 'public'
I am using the tool pgloader to copy all tables and table schema from an SQLite database to our postgres instance. The tool works great and does a great job automatically mapping the table schema and copying the tables, but the data outputs to the "public" schema within postgres. I cannot figure out for the life of me how to have pgloader export to a different schema. Has anyone figured this out?
I tried using the "ALTER SCHEMA" command but it still output to the public schema.
Here is my config script:
LOAD DATABASE
     FROM sqlite:///Users/downloads/Downloads/SQLite_ENTIRE_test.db
     INTO postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost/Test

     WITH include drop, create tables, create indexes, reset sequences, prefetch rows = 1000;


Probably easiest solution is to change search_path in your postgresql.conf to have the schema you want the objects installed into as the first one.

The docs mention --set command line option you could probably use to --set "search_path='your_new_schema, public'". You could also set that up along with other things as a --before script.

Try the command with this connection string postgresql://myuser:mypassword@localhost/mydb?options=--search_path=my_schema

In your target table you can also set the schema for this table: TARGET TABLE [ "<schema>" ]."<table name>" See https://pgloader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command.html

@AdrianKlaver That worked ! setting the schema in the search_path wihtin my config file did the trick!
     `SET search_path to 'import';`

